# How to direct VS2015 Unit Test project to output to custom directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I create a unit test in my VS2015 project for testing my library through msdn project template.
The default output directory is at $(SolutionDir) but I have a custom output directory which will store all projects output under one solution. e.g. Bin folder.[Please refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khwJ7.png)
When I change the output directory at General Tab through property page, the unit test will failed to run.
Is anyone also facing the same problem as me?

Comment: There are probably other directories that need to be updated as well. You'll just need to dig in deeper and see where the mismatch is.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post to be more readable and replying me. Yeah, I am still looking for the mismatch. Will update the post if I found the solution.

Comment: What are the errors you receive in the unit test?